# How to hide defaultAxisTickStretegy while the chart is loading in LightningChart Js?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

How to hide defaultAxisTickStretegy while the chart is loading in LightningChart Js

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide axes ticks you should set tickStyle to emptyTick. Here is a 2 points line series chart example with the hidden ticks:

```
// Import LightningChartJS
const lcjs = require('@arction/lcjs')
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    emptyTick
} = lcjs
// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY().setTitle('Empty ticks')
// Hide ticks for both axes
chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStyle(emptyTick)
chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTickStyle(emptyTick)
// Add line series
const series = chart.addLineSeries()
const points = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 100, y: 100}]
// Add points to the series
series.add(points)
```